# Groovy Map vs. Table Relations within Domain Classes - How to decribe & persist this?

Tags: java, grails, associative-array, relation

In Grails/Gorm I am storing a **physical site** which **holds objects** at **defined positions**.

The domain class would simply be:

#### EXAMPLE A

*SITE DC*

- sitename
- positionmap (1: dog, 2: cat, 3:foo, 4:bar, ... up to an average of 30 items)

... but the objects change their positions and I need to later be able to see WHICH positions were occupied by WHAT at a given time (WHEN).

Thus I added another domain class

#### EXAMPLE B

*POSITIONS DC*

- validfrom
- validto
- positionmap (1: dog, 2: cat, 3:foo, 4:bar)
- belongsTo *SITE*

*SITE DC*

- sitename

As all the objects will have a description AND there will be loads of SITEs using the same objects in it, I added a domain class to hold each and every OBJECT. Result:

#### EXAMPLE C

*OBJECT DC*

- name
- description

*POSITIONS DC*

- validfrom
- validto
- positionmap (1: reference_to_dog, 2: reference_to_cat, 3:reference_to_foo, 4:reference_to_bar)
- belongsTo *SITE*

*SITE DC*

- sitename

*Now the Map, to me, doesn't seem reasonable anymore.*

I am thinking about removing the map, replacing it by yet another domain class:

#### EXAMPLE D

*OBJECT DC*

- name
- description

*OBJECT-TO-POSITION DC*

- positionnumber (1, 2, 3, 4, ...)
- object (reference_to_cat, reference_to_dog, reference_to_foo, ...)
- belongsTo *POSITIONS*

*POSITIONS DC*

- validfrom
- validto
- belongsTo *SITE*

*SITE DC*

- sitename

#### QUESTIONS

1. Is it generally a good/bad idea to put maps into the database?
2. How could this be achieved easier?
3. What's the most performant way to do it?

#### EDIT: A NEW APPROCH BASED ON ROBS ANSWER

Inspired by your suggestion, Rob, I drafted this data model which grants a "front-row" role to the "SeasonPlan" (amended "ResidenceHistory").

```
class Zoo {
    static hasMany = [seasons: SeasonPlan]
    String name
}

// one way of representing histories
class SeasonPlan = {
    static belongsTo = [zoo: Zoo] // a SeasonPlan belongs to a single particular Zoo
    static hasMany = [cages: Cage]
    DateTime from
    DateTime until
}

class Cage {
    static belongsTo = [seasonPlan: SeasonPlan] // a cage belongs to a single seasonplan
    Species species // a cage has a single Species
    Integer cageNumber
}

class Species {
    // static hasMany = [cages: Cage] // commented out - no reverse-lookup necessary
    String name
}
```

This has one drawback: For every season plan there's a new cage - though *in reality the cages stay the same*! (Imagine a "Integer squareMeters" within the "Cage" to make it more obvious why this isn't desired.)

For me applying such a thing to a data model is often hard to comprehend - **how do I fit "pseudo-static" data like this into the application while retaining real-world corelation?**

I hope what I mean is understandable - sorry if not.

Comment: As for your update, that probably depends. It just takes some experience, I suppose. I guess I'd recommend asking another question and getting others' opinions on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still trying to understand your domain; you may be overcomplicating things a bit. Would this basic model work? If not, can you explain why? I'll update my example if I can better understand your conditions.

*Edit - updated example given the comments below.*

```
class Cage {
    static belongsTo = [zoo: Zoo] // a cage belongs to a single particular Zoo
    Species species // a cage has a single Species
    String name
}

class Zoo {
    static hasMany = [cages: Cage]
    String name
}

class Species {
    static hasMany = [cages: Cage] // a species can be in many different cages
    String name
}

// one way of representing histories
class ResidenceHistory = {
    Species species
    Cage cage
    DateTime from
    DateTime until
}
```

Here's how you might use the domain, then:

```
def sanDiego = new Zoo(name: 'San Diego Zoo').save()
def aviary = new Cage(name: 'Aviary', zoo: sanDiego).save()
def elephantCage = new Cage(name: 'Elephant Area, Cage 5', zoo: sanDiego).save()

def bird = new Species(name: 'Blue-Footed Booby', cage: aviary).save()
def elephant = new Species(name: 'Asian Elephant', cage: elephantCage).save()

new ResidenceHistory(species: bird, cage: aviary, from: new DateTime(), to: new DateTime().plusDays(20)).save()
```

To answer your listed questions specifically:

1. It depends - usually I'd prefer using the database's relational capabilities instead of storing maps in the database. It's much easier to work with the raw data if they aren't serialized Java objects.
2. See my example above.
3. This shouldn't matter unless performance becomes an issue. Use the solution that makes the most sense and is the easiest to maintain, and if you find that it causes performance problems, profile your application and fix the problems individually.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate answers, Rob.

For simplicity reasons, I didn't share the whole scope of the requirement. The "history" needs to be available just like current timeframes (validfrom-validto).

Think of it as ZOO, CAGE, SPECIES. We have a lot of zoos with their cages. Each cage holds one specific species.

One species can be in a lot of zoos and in a lot the corresponding cages.
Every species has an elaborate description.

Now one zoo can take a species from the DB and associate it with a cage in a given timeframe. (thus no actual moving => history for moving doesn't work)

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's bare-bones, but it's my interpretation of how you might get started with your domain. If I've erred in my assumptions, let me know and I'll try and make adjustments.

Comment: A very good approach - already easier to comprehend than my own! I will post a new suggestion in a second and I'm eager to hear your thoughts on it!